# One to many relationship with ensuring at least 1 record exists in (many table)

Tags: sql, t-sql

How would you design tables in the following scenerio.

I have two tables in one-to-many relationship.

```
Table A - One
Table B - Many
```

Such relation doesn't give me
on database level the protection that at least 1 record will be present in B table.

Moreover Table A should know the last identifier from Table B (basing on any rule).

How could I accomplish such a task?

Comment: Can you give some examples of data that is allowed and not allowed, to be sure that your question is ulta-clear?

Comment: @GordonLinoff e.g. definition and versions. table A should point to the last version from tableB and has history of all versions.

Comment: Do it with a trigger - insert in A will insert in B.

Comment: @John - He was hoping you'd provide a sample layout and data, and tweaking your question to read something like "What should I change?".  In general, `A` won't have a reference to `B` (because `B` will have the reference to `A`), because it would be counter to good normalization practices.  And usually you can conceptually have empty collections anyways.  You can do things with trigger or check constraints.  Getting the "Last Entry" in `B` is derived information, and you should probably code up a view or table-valued stored procedure for that.

Answer (score 1):

The foreign key will be in Table B which will guarantee that every row will have a corresponding row in Table A. In a one-to-one relationship, you could have a redundant FK in Table A to guarantee the reverse, but for a one-to-many, that's not possible.

I came across a similar requirement a few years ago when I designed a method for maintaining versions of data. Table A would be the static or unchanging data (or just data that may change but was not necessary to track) and Table B contained each version of the data as it changed. My solution was to force all DML access to the tables through a view. Actually there were two main views, one which performed a one-to-many join which provided a complete history of the data changes. This had a "do nothing" trigger on it to render it read only (one shouldn't be able to change history). The other was a one-to-one join of the static data and only the current version. This provided the data as it existed "now." All DML went through this view.

When a row was inserted, the trigger inserted into both tables their prospective fields. When a row was updated, the static fields (if changed) was updated and the versioned data was inserted as a new row. Deletions were handled as a soft delete.

The point is, there was no way to insert only to the static table. Even if all the versioned fields of a new row happened to contained NULLs, those fields were still inserted into the versioned table. So it was not possible to have a row in Table A (my static table) that did not have at least one corresponding row in Table B (my versioned table).